# Mock injection propagate

Tags: spring, junit, mocking, easymock, code-injection

How can I,

propagate a mock service created in a unit test? I would like, that spring when the test starts uses as bean injection of the service, the service mock.

Thanks.

Regards.

Comment: Can you please clarify a little more on what you are trying to do? I didn't really get it

Comment: try @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html

Comment: I resolve, add un Wrap type this method: public static Object unWrapInterface(Object proxiedInstance) throws Exception {
  if (proxiedInstance instanceof Advised) {
   return unWrapInterface((Object) ((Advised) proxiedInstance).getTargetSource().getTarget());
  }
  return proxiedInstance;
 }